# How to calculate the battery level at a given point of time in Android

Tags: android

Hey I am trying to find out the battery level at a specific time. I have seen tuitorials that implement the broadcast reciever and calculate the battery level onReceive(). But doesn't that mean that the level will be calculated when there is a broadcast?(eg. like a broadcast abt change in battery level)? I wanted to know how can I find the battery level at that specific instant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But doesn't that mean that the level will be calculated when there is a broadcast?

It's more that when the battery level changes, a broadcast is sent out.

> I wanted to know how can I find the battery level at that specific instant?

Technically speaking, you can't.

What you *can* do is find out the last-broadcast `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` broadcast -- IOW, the level of the battery the last time Android told everyone about the battery level:

```
registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED))
```

This will return the last-broadcast `Intent` (as the battery-change broadcast is sticky). `BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL` and `BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE` are keys to extras containing information about the battery level.